# detecting specific argument exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch, argumentexception

I need to catch a specific ArgumentException.

> System.ArgumentException: Input array is longer than the number of
>   columns in this table.

I noticed that there are a number of ArugmentExceptions that can occur, but how would I go about catching this one specifically? "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table"

unfortunately doing `catch(ArgumentException ex)` is not specific enough...

We are uploading a tab delimited file and the exception above tells us to tell the user to check the number of columns in the file and to try again.

Comment: What's throwing the exception? I'd expect you to be able to validate the condition *before* calling the relevant method, rather than by catching the exception. ArgumentException represents a *programming* failure - you shouldn't normally catch it.

Comment: Using a tab delimited file to add rows to a table. If the there are more tabs in the file than table columns, it throws this error. The feature was designed for machine generated files which are never wrong but some people have been generating files to upload in excel which is becoming error prone. I just want to be able to feed back to the user than there are too many columns in the file they are uploading.

Answer (score 5):

Don't catch the exception - avoid it happening in the first place. You have the input, so you know how many columns have been provided. You know the table you're adding the data to, so you know how many columns are available.

You can - and **should** check the validity of the data before you try to add the rows. It's as simple as that.

`ArgumentException` should almost *never* be caught and "handled". It should be an indication of the caller providing a bad argument *that could have been verified beforehand*. That's a programming problem, and should be fixed by adding appropriate code on the calling side.

Comment: to validate the layout, i would need to count the number of tab chars on each line in the text file... how would i do this?

Comment: @Stuart: Well I would use a TSV library of some description so as to convert the text-only data into a more semantically useful form first. You *may* be able to get away with just `line.Split('\t')` but you're likely to need to take escaping into account etc. You haven't told us anything about the API you're using, which makes this tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse/analyse the exception message, because there is no extra information available. `ArgumentException`s are typically not meant to be caught, because they indicate a programming error. That's why there's no extra information.

Note that parsing the exception message can be error prone, since your application might be rolled out to Windows machines with a different culture. In that case the .NET version might throw localized exception messages.

Comment: See my comment on Damien's answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think we're on the same wave length here. I hinted that this is a bad idea by saying: "ArgumentExceptions are typically not meant to be caught, because they indicate a programming error".

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd have made that the *first* thing - we don't know that the OP "will have to parse/analyse the exception message"... the first approach should *not* be to do that, but to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to catch the `ArgumentException`, inspect it, and if it's not the one that interests you, re-throw it.

```
catch(ArgumentException ex) {
  if(ex.ParamName!="specificargument" || ex.Message != "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table")
     throw;
  //Handle exception, inform user
}
```

(Different checks may be more appropriate - I.e. it may not be appropriate to check the entire message text)

It would be better if the checks for the specific type could be performed without having to re-`throw` exceptions that don't match - and that's exactly what exception filters were invented for. Unfortunately, C# has never surfaced this feature (despite it existing in IL, and even exposed in [VB.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dy8x9k9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Catching the exception is a really bad idea here. Avoid it happening in the first place.

Comment: @JonSkeet - you're assuming that their code has an easy way to interrogate the table information beforehand. This may not be the case. We don't know what API they're dealing with and getting back an `ArgumentException` from.

Comment: That's why I asked the question about context before adding an answer - I'd be enormously surprised to find an API which allowed me to add rows to a table without also providing a way of querying the metadata. If it turns out it *is* impossible to do that, then we could fall back on catching the exception if absolutely necessary - but it should be viewed as a last resort having explored all other possible avenues.